# creating a piano with react.js, use of state unclear

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-class-based-component

I'm about to build up a keyboard for a piano and I want to use state in order handel the pressed and non pressed keys (keys that finally generate the sound, so that I can play single notes and chords)

I modified an online tutorial the following way: First of all I created these objects:

```
export const NOTES = [
  { name: "c", accid: "natural", hz: 3270, keyboard: "q" },
  { name: "d", accid: "flat", hz: 3465, keyboard: "2" },
  { name: "d", accid: "natural", hz: 3671, keyboard: "w" },
  { name: "e", accid: "flat", hz: 3889, keyboard: "3" },
  { name: "e", accid: "natural", hz: 4120, keyboard: "e" },
  { name: "f", accid: "natural", hz: 4365, keyboard: "r" },
  { name: "g", accid: "flat", hz: 4625, keyboard: "5" },
  { name: "g", accid: "natural", hz: 4900, keyboard: "t" },
  { name: "a", accid: "flat", hz: 5191, keyboard: "6" },
  { name: "a", accid: "natural", hz: 5500, keyboard: "z" },
  { name: "b", accid: "flat", hz: 5827, keyboard: "7" },
  { name: "b", accid: "natural", hz: 6174, keyboard: "u" },
];
```

My first step is to load the pressed keyboard keys into an array that is hooked up to the global state object. Later on I want to create a sound for all the objects represented by the keyboard keys which are represented in that state array. But first things first.

Why is **this.state.pressedKeys** (spread operator) undefined, when I press a key?

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'pressedKeys' of undefined*

```
import React from "react";
import Key from "./Key";
import "./Piano.css";
import { NOTES } from "../global/constants";

class Piano extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pressedKeys: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  //  window.addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyUp);
  };

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.repeat) {
      return;
    }

    const key = event.key;
    const updatedPressedKeys = [...this.state.pressedKeys];
    if (!updatedPressedKeys.includes(key)) {
      updatedPressedKeys.push(key);
    }

    this.setState({
      pressedKeys: updatedPressedKeys,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const keys = NOTES.map((note) => {
      return (
        <Key
          key={note.hz}
          note={note.name}
          accid={note.accid}
          pressedKeys={this.state.pressedKeys}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div className="piano">{keys}</div>;
  }
}

export default Piano;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed binding the `this` of the class component to the `handleKeyDown` callback, so `this` isn't referring to the component. This results in `this.state` being undefined in the callback.

In order of preference:

1. You can bind using arrow function.

   ```
   handleKeyDown = event => { .... }
   ```
2. You can bind in the constructor.

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { pressedKeys: [] };

     this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
   }
   ```
3. You can bind when attaching/passing prop.

   ```
   window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
   ```

I suggest also using a functional state update to compute if key is included and create the next state if necessary.

```
handleKeyDown = event => {
  if (event.repeat) {
    return;
  }

  const { key } = event;

  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (prevState.pressedKeys.includes(key)) {
      return prevState;
    }
    return {
      pressedKeys: [...prevState.pressedKeys, key],
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok, handelKeyUp also works, also by using a functional state update. I use state in order to tggle the keys of the keyboard. Should I map the keyboard keys to my NOTES array, or would it be btter to load the complete array objects into state: { name: "c", accid: "natural", hz: 3270, keyboard: "q" },...

Comment: @user1953346 If you meant mapping the `NOTES` to an array including keypress handlers, I think that would be ok. Since the `NOTES` array itself is "static" I don't think it makes sense to store it in state unless I'm missing *some* aspect of you wanting to update any of that data.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I can give out colored keys now, thanks. There is one strange behaviour, the handelKeyDown() function above stops after 3 or 4 pressed keys. Principally I should be able to press 12 keys at the same time. This problem must be independent from handleKeyUp since I press all the keys without releasing them

Comment: @user1953346 Is this possibly a limit of concurrent key presses your keyboard can handle/allows?

Comment: It seems to be like that, I would need a gaming keyboard or a piano with a midi interface, but that's another topic, thanks!